# Sugarcrm 6.5 after deleting all the dashlets from right hand side, could not able to drag and drop from left hand side dashlets

Tags: sugarcrm

Sugarcrm 6.5 after deleting all the dashlets from right hand side, could not able to drag and drop from left hand side dashlets.

Please let me know if anyone has solution for this issue

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I know of is to reset the dashlet page to default settings inside your user profile. On top of your user profile there is a button reset starting page. Klick on it and you should have both sides back.

Comment: Thanks i will try and let you know